# Grid search error in LIBSVM while optimizing C and g parameters

Tags: machine-learning, svm, matlab, libsvm

I am using libsvm for a one-class classification problem. I am trying to select the ideal C and gamma parameters for different kernels(polynomial, linear and rbf) I am using the suggested matlab code that finds the the best parameters through a v-fold validation technique.

```
bestcv = 0;
for log2c = -1:3,
  for log2g = -4:1,
    cmd = ['-v 5 -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g)];
    cv = svmtrain(Target_train, train, cmd);
    if (cv >= bestcv),
      bestcv = cv; bestc = 2^log2c; bestg = 2^log2g;
    end
    fprintf('%g %g %g (bestc=%g, g=%g, rate=%g)\n', log2c, log2g, cv, bestc, bestg, bestcv);
  end
end
```

In v-fold cross-validation, we first divide the training set into v subsets of equal size. Sequentially one subset is tested using the classifier trained on the remaining v − 1 subsets. Thus, each instance of the whole training set is predicted once so the cross-validation accuracy is the percentage of data which are correctly classified.

In this code, the C and gamma take values in a range of (2^-1, 2^3) and (2^-4, 2^1)

I noticed that when the svmtrain function is called there is no specified parameter for -s which controls the the type of svm. The default parameter for -s in libsvm is 0 which is for C-SVC. I have a one-class clssification problem so I should be using -s 2 according to svmtrain options. However when I modify the 4th line of the above code into

```
cmd = ['-s 2 -v 5 -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g)];
```

I am getting this error:

Undefined function 'ge' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in ergasia (line 37) if (cv >= bestcv),

For what I know, svm returns a model of type struct. My question is, is the code I am using suitable for parameter selection in a one class classification problem?

An other question: Is there a better way of defining the best C and gamma other than that? I found this method here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf

I could really use some help with that so thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of cross-validation with LIBSVM is a score. LIBSVM's internal cross-validation uses accuracy as score metric, which is known to be suboptimal for model selection. It would be better to use a measure like area under the ROC curve (which you can compute using `perfcurve` if you have the statistics toolbox). Your code seems okay at first glance, except that one-class SVM uses the `nu` parameter, not `C`.

You could use specialized libraries like [Optunity](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#) to do the hyperparameter tuning for you. It offers more efficient routines than grid search to optimize hyperparameters (e.g. which require less parameter pairs to be tested) and has built-in cross-validation with score metrics of your choosing so you don't have to bother implementing it yourself. Optunity is available in MATLAB ([example](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/matlab/lssvmlab/regression.html)).

Disclaimer: I'm the main developer of Optunity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am definetly going to check Optunity. However, this is a university assignment so I am not allowed to use any software other than LIBSVM, let alone I am required to write my own code for this specific task.

Comment: So the nu replaces c parameter in one-class svm?